# MVC 4 - How do I properly execute a URL in a View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an MVC 4 View. One of the properties is 'Url'. I'm displaying the value of the URL in a field in this view and when a user clicks on it, I'd like to execute the URL. I have this code:

```
<div class="display-label">
     @Html.DisplayName("Url")
</div>
<div class="display-field">
    <a href="@Model.Url">@Model.Url</a>
</div>
```

The problem is when the user clicks on this URL (I'm using www.microsoft.com as a test), I get the following error:

```
Requested URL
   http://localhost:52070/HousingBuyerSearch/Details/www.microsoft.com
```

So it seems I'm doing something wrong because it's attempting to call a method on a controller. I'm still fairly new to all this so I'm not entirely sure how to fix this.

Comment: How are you populating Model.Url?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I'm populating it in the controller, after I read the value in from a database table. The value is stored as 'www.microsoft.com'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in this case is your `Url` does not start with a protocol (IE `http://`) - so the browser is interpreting this as a relative url to your document.  You'll want to add some logic to your app to ensure that external urls start with a protocol, something like this:

```
var url = "www.microsoft.com";
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url) && !url.StartsWith("http://")) {
    url = "http://" + url;
}
```